# creating new access 2010 database file or opening an old one cause reconfiguration

Tags: ms-office, ms-access-2010

On my win7 64 bit PC, I have installed office 2010. It also has office 2003. When I open the ACCESS 2010 program, it is OK but When I create a new ACCESS 2010 database file or open an old one, it reconfigures itself. Very annoying ... I searched and tried many ways but it got worse. Ran the famous reg command, still did not help.

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Access\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1

reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Comment: So you need that your older 2003 database opens in 2010 when you click on it? Or do you want to use both versions of Access? Did you check this http://allenbrowne.com/bug-17.html ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reconfigure"? The file type associations break? I once solved such a problem with a simple repair run from the office 2010 setup menu.

Comment: under 2010, each time i try to create a new database file or open an old one, the dialog "configuration progress" or similar starts. I ran repair from the programs inside the control panel and did not help. which repair do you mean?.